# English-based riddle for a word

Tags: riddle, word

I wrote a riddle for a word about a year ago. I don't know how hard it is, but it becomes pretty obvious *after* you know the answer. Here it is:

```
River, Sing, Emit
Rear, Ranging, Mite
An acronym of its measurement
Is the first of synonym
It does not have a synonym
It does not have an antonym
Its anagram appears twice
Its clues are a homonym
When it's over, it is up
It controls us - a reality
We control it - a fantasy, imagination
Three of its letters appear in every line
Its third letter is missed in three
What is the word that has been mentioned?
```

There is no spelling, grammatical or formatting mistake, any such 'mistake' could be intended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is:

> Time

River, Sing, Emit
Rear, Ranging, Mite

> Reversing "emit". Re-arranging "mite".

An acronym of its measurement
Is the first of synonym

> Not sure. Maybe first refers to "one" which is an anagram of "eon".

It has no synonym
It has no antonym

> Both are true of time.

Its anagram appears twice
Its clues are a homonym

> I believe this is a clue to interpreting the first two lines.

When it's over, it is up

> It's over and time's up mean the same thing.

It controls us - a reality
We control it - a fantasy, imagination

> We are mortal and our time is coming. Time travel is fantasy.

Three of its letters appear in every line
Its third letter is missed in three

> T, I and E appear in each line. M is missing from lines 9, 10 and 12.

Comment: That was quick. I'm impressed with this site.

Comment: `E` doesn't appear in `It has no synonym` and `It has no antonym`.
`I, N and T` appear in each line, `M` is missing in three lines (9, 10, 12).

Comment: The first of `synonym` is `s` = `second`, a unit of measurement.

Comment: @f.rodrigues Oops, I meant to write "It does not have a synonym".